# How to use \t from form input to a tab for writing file? (\\t to \t)

Tags: python, python-3.6

From a HTML form `<input>` where the user could write a `\t` I want to write a file with this value a separator

```
fic.write(separator.join(data)) # data is a list
```

But the problem is that the separator is written as-it and not its special meaning :

- Actual output `data1\tdata2\t...`
- Expected output `data1        data2        data3...`

How to get the special meaning of `\t` to achieve that ?

---

The problem can be seen as

```
print(separator == "\\t") # true but expect false 
print(separator == "\t") # false but expect true
```

Comment: is the variable `data` a `list / array`

Comment: @Jeril actually a list but I don’t think this matters

Comment: when I tied `f.write('\t'.join(data))` I am getting your expected result in the txt file, where are your seeing your `actual ouput` is it in the terminal or in the file?

Comment: @Jeril if you don’t understand the whole purpose of the question, try the simplify version : the 2 last lines ;) make them correct (see comment)

Comment: @azro: Show the binary output of `separator`.

Comment: Its 1011100 1110100 , exactly like \\t

Comment: @azro: It's **two** chars, therfore `separator == "\\t"` **is `True`**. Nothing wrong, the first `'\'` escapes the second.I assume dataflow from `HTML form` escapes the `'\'` from the input.

Answer (score 1):

I try this and works for me, I dont think this is the best approach but it works.

```
In [1]: separator = "\\t"

In [2]: separator
Out[2]: '\\t'

In [3]: sep = eval("str('{}')".format(separator))

In [4]: separator is '\t'
Out[4]: False

In [5]: sep is '\t'
Out[5]: True
```

This solution should work with others like '\n' and should not modify the usuals like ',' or ';'.

Comment: Doing eval() on stuff from an HTML forms feels like a recipe for disaster. What if the user types '+sys.exit(0)+' or something like that?

Comment: @TurePålsson That's why I said that is no the best approach. In the case of use this method you should make some checks before.

Answer (score -1):

I tried this:

```
data = ["data1","data2","data3","data4"]
saveFile = open('file.txt','w')
saveFile.write("\t".join(data))
saveFile.close()
```

Output:

```
data1   data2   data3   data4
```

Comment: This will work, obviously, but he trys to take the separator as an argument from a html form. The problem is that it takes the \t as a 2 separate chars when they have to be interpret as 1.

Comment: Seriously ? Please take your time to read again my question. I know some python, not so much but clearly the basics and your answer is a basic, read the end of my question, if you reach the true/false expected you’ll be done ;)